# If condition with a ternary operator and a Greater than(>) symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am confused with the following piece of code

```
bool i_am = true;
int he_is= 0;
if ((!i_am? false : he_is> 0))
    Console.WriteLine("Condition is true.....");
```

i have tested tried all possible ways to understand by testing it with different possibilities of i_am and he_is but still am not able to find the logic.

**Tried removing one set of the braces "()" and it produces a different output.**
The braces work confusingly as well! why is this?

I am a beginner in C#,could anyone please help me with the flow of code in this condition statement.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? An `if` requires a `bool`. The conditional operator `?` returns one. Either the first after the question mark if the test was positive, otherwise the one behind `:`. `he_is> 0` returns `false`. Since both are false the `if` won't exeute the `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Same as `i_am && he_is > 0`

Comment: @juharr you just nailed it! Short and sweet!
Thank you so much!

Comment: post it as an answer, it may help people like me.. @juharr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we analyze it piece by piece:

```
!i_am ? false : he_is > 0
```

is equal to typing:

```
if (!i_am) //The ! operator means "NOT", so its like saying if(i_am = false), while the default if(i_am) would be equal to if(i_am = true)
{
     return false;
}
else 
{
     return he_is > 0; //he_is = 0, so 0 > 0 will return false.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The if condition is expressed in a weird form, but I think it is equal to:

```
if (i_am && he_is > 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what part is confusing you, so I'm going to assume a little bit.

The "??" operating is referred to as the Null Coalescing Operator.  It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Does that clear anything up?

Comment: That's not true. The Null Coalescing Operator is `??`.

Comment: Apologies - added another ? - I assumed that is the operator he was going for.

Comment: He is using the [?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ty67wk28.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in his code.

Comment: Also known as the "Safe Navigation Operator" - Right? 

Also here is the English [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for others.

Comment: No :) The [Safe Navigation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#C.23) is used if you want to access a member or call a method of an object but don't know if it is `null`. The `?:` operator is called [Conditional Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).